# What are the alternatives to Core-Plot for drawing graphs in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, core-plot

Are there any alternatives to Core-Plot for drawing graphs in iPhone SDK?

I am having hard time integrating core-plot in my app. Lot of issues.

Can you please suggest some alternatives to core-plot?

Comment: Too late, but check out TapKu library's excellent graph:  http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-graph

Comment: @sudorm-rf Unfortunately there is no such thing as Tapku library's graph. Not anymore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some of the alternatives that I found were:

http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/ (discontinued)

[https://www.scichart.com/](https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-features) (good alternative to Shinobi)

https://github.com/sweetynebhwani/deSimpleChart

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I hope this helps.

Comment: original deSimpleChart repo is not available now. Try https://github.com/duivesteyn-net/deSimpleChart

Comment: I would rather suggest adding some descriptions or useful code snippets from desired links (which developers can build on) in the answer. As this some of these links are going down, there may be a time when this answer would not be useful because of dead links.

Comment: @palaniraja: Your link is also dead.

Comment: @ParthBhatt thanks for the headsup. Found a fork. https://github.com/sweetynebhwani/deSimpleChart

Answer (score 3):

If what you intend to draw is relatively easy, you may get quick results by using Quartz and drawing the graph yourself. Just subclass an `UIView` and override its `drawRect:` method.

---

A very, very simple example of drawing a square, 10x50 pixels at a fixed position, via Quartz:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorRef red = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

    CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(10.f, 20.f, 10.f, 50.f);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, red);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, barRect);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample code which would create a simple bar chart? Thanks!

Comment: No problem. This is very simple of course, from there you can look for other Quartz examples if you want to go the do-it-yourself way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP asked his questions, there has been an abundance of new chart libraries. [GraphKit](https://github.com/michalkonturek/GraphKit), [TWRCharts](https://github.com/chasseurmic/TWRCharts), to name only two. [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) lists a lot more, if you do a search for 'graph'. So I'd like to gather more feedback with regards to this question.

Answer (score 0):

iOSPlot, iOS:Chart, KeepEdge Library, Shinobi Controls