# what is the best way to draw mathematical graphs in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, math

I might think there are some way to draw graphs related mathematics, for example by using quartz, OpenGL ES, cocos2D.
But I am really confusing what is best library and best how for how to implement that in iphone or ipad.
In addition to, what is the best libray for calculating scientific math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is anything out there currently that's dedicated to drawing mathematical graphs, but there are several charting libraries that could display your data nicely. I think you would have to provide your own data in most cases though.

There's a list of charting libraries available here:

[What are the alternatives to Core-Plot for drawing graphs in iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065416/what-are-the-alternatives-to-core-plot-for-drawing-graphs-in-iphone-sdk)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and references, but i'm confusing still. Besides, most alternative library link is broken.

Comment: Perhaps its time the list was checked and updated - I wasn't aware that some of the links were duds, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz or OpenGL ES for drawing. There is a nice demo by apple about "QuartzDemo" for this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: which do you think is proper solution with mathematical precision?