# Has anyone compiled iGraph, graph layout library, for iOS?

Tags: ios, igraph

Is it possible to compile [iGraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/), graph layout library for iOS?

Comment: Why this question is off topic?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't. I don't know anybody who has. But I've also never heard of it before.

The website claims it is written in C/C++, so in theory you should be able to get it running on iOS. You may need to make some modifications.

Looking more closely at the documentation, it appears to be a plain C API (even better!) so it should be fairly easy to compile for iOS. You will probably have to edit the Makefiles to have it cross-compile for ARM (instead of Intel).

However, the source code is published under the GNU GPL. There are clauses in the GPL that conflict with clauses in the Apple Developer Program Agreement (I forget the specifics but it should be easy enough to research). This means that if you got it working in an app, you couldn't put it on the App Store without either Apple or the iGraph developers offering you different terms.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about iGraph, but I've been thinking of trying [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). 
It's a graph plotting 3rd-party iOS framework. 
Not a lot of documentation, but you can see some apps that already use it if you browse their site.

Not sure why you got voted down. Happens.

Edit:

Oh, in that case, this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074186/1126783

Comment: Thanks, but as I know, core plot is a library for charts and graph, I mean graph in the mathematical sense, some vertices and edges between them. I need a library to layout mathematical graphs.